# No signature of method for running cucumber test when using cucumber v1.2.4

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I'm having a problem with setting up the developing environment of my own. I'm using eclipse phontom with `eclipse-groovy` and `Cucumber Eclipse plugin`, and want to join the development that write test codes using groovy and cucumber.

At first I import dependency for cucumber (`io.cucumber.cucumber-groovy:4.5.3`) through maven , and everything works fine. However, some days later, colleagues had told me that they used to import dependency with older version (`info.cukes.cucumber-groovy:1.2.4`). And everything is broken in my laptop after downgrade.

For example, following is a simple step definition of `Given`.

```
package steps

import cucumber.api.groovy.EN
import cucumber.api.groovy.Hooks

this.metaClass.mixin(EN)
this.metaClass.mixin(Hooks)

Given(/an item ID which does not exist/) { ->
    documentId = "test_not_exist_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()
}
```

And when I run it on my laptop, the following exception is raised.

```java
No signature of method: steps.RawItemRetrieval.Given() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, steps.RawItemRetrieval$_run_closure1) values: [an item ID which does not exist, steps.RawItemRetrieval$_run_closure1@45d2ade3]
Possible solutions: grep(), run(), run(), find(), every()
    at cucumber.runtime.groovy.GroovyBackend.loadGlue(GroovyBackend.java:85)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:91)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:69)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:65)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:35)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Is there anything I should do to make things work under dependency `info.cukes.cucumber-groovy:1.2.4`?

Following are my development environment which may be relevant:

```
JDK: Amazon Corretto-8.212.04.2 (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
Maven: 3.3.9
Groovy compiler in eclipse: 2.4.17
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So you first used Cucumber 4.5 and it worked, and then you downgraded to 1.2.4 and things stopped working. The proper fix would be to revert that downgrade and use the latest cucumber instead. You are likely using features that didn't exist in the older version.

Comment: However, the code seems work in my colleagues' laptop. Besides, as I understand, the error states that method `Given()` is not found, but I assume that it should be provided by cucumber....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I have found the reason. Maybe it is caused by cucumber 1.2.4 does not support step definition in the following format:

```
Given(/an item ID which does not exist/) { ->
    ....
}
```

When I change the style to regex format, it works again.

```
Given(~/^an item ID which does not exist$/) { ->
    ....
}
```

Thanks Mark Rotteveel for the suggestion!